# PHP generated table in html email

Tags: php, html, email

I am generting a table with PHP and then send this table as an HTML-Email. So far it works fine.

But when I open it with Gmail (didn't have the chance to try it with other clients), Gmail breaks the raw HTML code and sometimes this breaks the HTML tags. For exemple:

```
<tr>
 <td>carapicuiba.cursosembelleze.com</t
 d>
<td>8</td><td>2</td> <td>10</td> <td>6</td> </tr>
```

As a result of this the table is not shown correctly. I already added spaces between all HTML tags to have Gmail break the lines at the spaces and not inside the tags but Gmail won't do me this favou :/

Any ideas what to do? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some extra code?

Comment: You will have to add some extra headers like,
"MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" and
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"

Comment: Adding "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" worked perfectly. Thanks!